# Circular Permutations. Difference between clockwise and anti-clockwise permutations.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

Please tell me the total number of permutations possible of the beads in a necklace where all the beads are distinct. The necklace consists of n distinct beads.

[image: Necklace picture having 4 distinct beads]

Answer as per me: the answer is $(n-1)!\:$, as the clockwise and anti-clockwise arrangements are different.

Answer given in various online courses: The clockwise arrangement of the necklace shown is B1-B2-B3-B4. Since the necklace can be flipped, the total permutations = (n-1)!/2. Reason: After flipping the necklace, the anti-clockwise arrangement is the same again i.e. B1-B2-B3-B4.
The link to these online courses are:

> 1) https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/permutations-and-combinations/circular-permutations.aspx
>
> 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BoAwmUlfqs>
>
> The 2nd link is a video lecture in the language of Hindi. Start this video from 13:05 minutes, so as to avoid the unnecessary things.

Can you tell me which one is correct with an appropriate explanation.

Comment: In combinatorics, a [necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) is invariant under rotation, while a bracelet is invariant under rotation and reflection.  There are $(n - 1)!$ necklaces and $(n - 1)!/2$ bracelets with distinct beads.

Answer (score 2):

It's only when one allows the necklace to be flipped over that division by 2 is needed. If one keeps the necklace say on a table and only rotates it (no fair picking necklace up in space) it's the $(n-1)!$ answer.

Comment: Hi coffeemath, so does this mean that if the circular arrangement is flippable, then total permutations are (n-1)!/2 irrespective of whether the clockwise arrangement and anti clockwise arrangement is equal or not?

Comment: If flippable, this means clockwise and anticlockwise arrangements are being viewed as equal, since when flipped the two types interchange. [It's not that the count is "irrespective" of whether the arrangements are equal, it's that the two types of arrangements are being counted as the same.]